# Android Studio Template package name

Tags: android, android-studio, templates

I tried make android studio template like activity template by [this instruction](https://coderwall.com/p/fsxvyw/file-templates-in-android-studio)

Current package set in globals.xml.ftl

```
 <global id="srcOut" value="${srcDir}/${slashedPackageName(packageName)}" />
```

and create template file

```
<instantiate from="src/app_package/LifecycleFragment.java.ftl"
               to="${escapeXmlAttribute(srcOut)}/${className}.java" />
```

It force my template file to src/main/java/myPackageName

But my current package is kotlin

How can i create template in current selected folder?

Comment: have you found an answer?

Comment: I have same troubles. Also flavours postfix is added to directory.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm late with my answer, but maybe it will be useful for someone.

To change the source package from java to kotlin try add this line to globals.xml.ftl:

```
<global id="kotlinMainSourceSet" value="${srcOut?replace('java','kotlin') />
```

Use it in your receipt.xml.ftl as following:

! Replace SomeClass.kt.ftl with your class in app_package;

! Replace your_needed_path with path, in which you would like to put the file

! Replace someClassName with the id of the className from template.

```
<instantiate
        from="src/app_package/SomeClass.kt.ftl"
        to="${escapeXmlAttribute(kotlinMainSourceSet)}/${your_needed_path}/${someClassName}.kt" />
```

In addition I'll answer on the @AlexeiKorshun question with which I've faced too: applicationIdSuffix is added, while creating a directory. This can be easily fixed by overriding srcOut in your globals.kt.ftl with following:

```
<global id="srcOut" value="${srcDir}/${slashedPackageName(packageName?replace('.dev|.qa2|.stage', '', 'r'))}" />
```

.dev/.qa2/.stage are added as an example,please replace them with yours.